# Merge javascript array keys into inner array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array generated by php that makes this:

```
var sections = [
    section1 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    section1 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    section1 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    section2 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    section2 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com]
]
```

What's the best way to make it:

```
var sections = [
    section1 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    section2 => 
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com],
    [name => anthony, email => test@test.com]
]
```

Merge all like keys and put all the inner arrays into the same pool.

So I can loop through each section as a "Section" and not parts of the same section.

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Comment: It's not real code it's an example.

Comment: Steps for good question: 1. Post actual JavaScript code. 2. Show us what you tried so far. 3. Reproduce particular issue in a demo.

Comment: Is the section number actually a property of the original elements? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-to-combine-an-array-in-javascript/24302781#24302781

Comment: JavaScript won't let you double up on the keys like that. If you have 'section1', assigning a new value to it will override the old one.

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is not valid JavaScript and so it is not obvious what structure you are looking for. Also, you shouldn't have PHP output problematic / duplicate JavaScript and then try to clean it up later in JavaScript, the PHP should be modified to produce good JavaScript. It shouldn't be difficult to store your output in a PHP array rather than just outputting it and then only output unique elements (sections) to JavaScript

That being said, there is a simple modification to the output you currently have to make it valid JavaScript. I went ahead and appended `"1"`, `"2"`, etc. to the end of the strings to make it apparent what happens to the duplicates:

```
var sections = {
    section1 :
    {name : "anthony1", email : "test@test.com1"},
    section1 :
    {name : "anthony2", email : "test@test.com2"},
    section1 :
    {name : "anthony3", email : "test@test.com3"},
    section2 :
    {name : "anthony4", email : "test@test.com4"},
    section2 :
    {name : "anthony5", email : "test@test.com5"},
};

console.log(sections.section1.name, sections.section1.email); // "anthony3" "test@test.com3"
console.log(sections.section2.name, sections.section2.email); // "anthony5" "test@test.com5"
```

Without the appended `"1"`, `"2"`, etc:

```
var sections = {
    section1 :
    {name : "anthony", email : "test@test.com"},
    section1 :
    {name : "anthony", email : "test@test.com"},
    section1 :
    {name : "anthony", email : "test@test.com"},
    section2 :
    {name : "anthony", email : "test@test.com"},
    section2 :
    {name : "anthony", email : "test@test.com"},
};

console.log(sections.section1.name, sections.section1.email); // "anthony" "test@test.com"
console.log(sections.section2.name, sections.section2.email); // "anthony" "test@test.com"
```