# How to get the earliest and latest dates from an array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My code is working as expected but I'm having a hard time finding and adding the `earliest_date`, the `next_date` and the `latest_date` from my data.

```js
let tasks_data = [
    {
      'id': 10376401,
      'name': 'closed',
      'notes': null,
      'start_date': '2017-12-23',
      'end_date': '2018-01-07',
      'start_time': null,
      'end_time': null,
      'color': '#f99bd0',
      'color_id': 5,
      'estimated_hours': 0,
      'done': false,
      'user_id': 961775,
      'project_id': null,
      'project': null,
      'folder_id': null,
      'weight': 0,
      'created_at': '2017-11-13T00:58:16.577+00:00',
      'updated_at': '2017-11-13T00:58:16.577+00:00',
      'deleted_at': null
    },
    {
      'id': 10438883,
      'name': '',
      'notes': null,
      'start_date': '2018-02-17',
      'end_date': '2018-02-17',
      'start_time': null,
      'end_time': null,
      'color': '#ccaf53',
      'color_id': 36,
      'estimated_hours': 0,
      'done': false,
      'user_id': 961775,
      'project_id': 1501267,
      'project': {
        'id': 1501267,
        'name': 'sue',
        'color': '#ccaf53',
        'color_id': 36,
        'client': null,
        'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00',
        'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00'
      },
      'folder_id': null,
      'weight': 0,
      'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:15:48.055+00:00',
      'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:15:48.055+00:00',
      'deleted_at': null
    },
    {
      'id': 10438875,
      'name': 'Sue',
      'notes': null,
      'start_date': '2018-01-27',
      'end_date': '2018-01-27',
      'start_time': null,
      'end_time': null,
      'color': '#ccaf53',
      'color_id': 36,
      'estimated_hours': 0,
      'done': false,
      'user_id': 961775,
      'project_id': 1501267,
      'project': {
        'id': 1501267,
        'name': 'sue',
        'color': '#ccaf53',
        'color_id': 36,
        'client': null,
        'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00',
        'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.459+00:00'
      },
      'folder_id': null,
      'weight': 0,
      'created_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:11.903+00:00',
      'updated_at': '2017-11-17T03:14:50.363+00:00',
      'deleted_at': null
    }
  ]

  var start_dates = new Array()
  var end_dates = new Array()
  var result = tasks_data.reduce(function (acc, item) {
    var task = acc.find(function (accItem) {
      return accItem.project_id == item.project_id
    })
    if (task && !Array.isArray(task.schedule)) {
      task.schedule = [task.schedule].concat({
        project_id: item.project_id,
        start_date: item.start_date,
        end_date: item.end_date,
        daily_estimate: item.estimated_hours,
      })
      task.start_dates.push(item.start_date)
      task.end_dates.push(item.end_date)
      task.next_start_dates.push(item.start_date)
    } else if (task && Array.isArray(task.schedule)) {
      task.schedule.push({
        project_id: item.project_id,
        start_date: item.start_date,
        end_date: item.end_date,
        daily_estimate: item.estimated_hours,
      })
      task.start_dates.push(item.start_date)
      task.end_dates.push(item.end_date)
      task.next_start_dates.push(item.start_date)
    } else {
      acc.push({
        project_id: item.project_id,
        schedule: {
          project_id: item.project_id,
          start_date: item.start_date,
          end_date: item.end_date,
          daily_estimate: item.estimated_hours,
        },
        start_dates: [item.start_date],
        end_dates: [item.end_date],
        next_start_dates: [item.start_date],
      })
    }

    return acc
  }, [])

  console.log(result) // I got the dates stored in an array. I will now use the final result to parse it and get the earliest, latest and next_start date. Don't know how to simplify it. 
  
  function getEarliest (array_dates) {
    return array_dates.reduce(function (pre, cur) {
      return Date.parse(pre) > Date.parse(cur) ? cur : pre
    })
  }
```

```html
<body>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
<p>Welcome to <strong>Foo</strong>.</p>
</body>
```

The "earliest" is the `start_date`, the latest is the `end_date` and for the `next_start` is also the `start_date` excluding the queried "earliest".

My expected output is:

```
[
{
  "project_id": null,
  "schedule": {
    "project_id": null,
    "start_date": "2017-12-23",
    "end_date": "2018-01-07",
    "daily_estimate": 0
  },
  earliest: "2017-12-23",
  latest: "2018-01-07",
  next_start: "2017-12-23"
},
  {
    "project_id": 1501267,
    "schedule": [
      {
        "project_id": 1501267,
        "start_date": "2018-02-17",
        "end_date": "2018-02-17",
        "daily_estimate": 0
      },
      {
        "project_id": 1501267,
        "start_date": "2018-01-27",
        "end_date": "2018-01-27",
        "daily_estimate": 0
      }
    ],
    earliest: "2018-01-27",
    latest: "2018-02-17",
    next_start: "2018-02-17"
  }
]
```

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Loop through the array, testing the dates against variables that hold the earliest and latest dates found so far. If the current date is earlier than the earliest, replace it. If it's later than the latest, replace it. At the end the variables will hold the dates you want.

Comment: sorry, I tried solving it my own. actually I have a function which will get the earliest & latest from an array of dates. My problem right now is that I seem not to able to put the correct dates in the array from my loop. I will update my question

Comment: It looks like you also need to group your data by project ID. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-combine-the-array-in-javascript/24302781#24302781