# Fetching N records excluding joined ones?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables (details omitted for brevity):

```
create table products (
    id,
    name 
)

create table tags (
    id,
    name
)

create table product_tags (
    product_id,
    tag_id
)
```

These tables are populated as follows:

```
--------
products
--------
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Rice |
| 2  | Bean |
| 3  | Milk |
+----+------+

----
tags
----
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Eat   |
| 2  | Drink |
| 3  | Seeds |
| 4  | Cow   |
+----+-------+
```

When fetching `products` I want the output to be formatted as:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Rice',
    tags: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Eat'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Seeds'
        },
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bean',
    tags: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Eat'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Seeds'
        },
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Milk',
    tags: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Drink'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Cow'
        },
    ]
}]
```

To accomplish this, what I'm doing is:

```
select 
  products.*,
  tags.id as tag_id, tags.name as tag_name
from products
left join product_tags map on map.product_id = products.id
left join tags on map.tag_id = tags.id
```

The output of which is:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Rice',
    tag_id: 1,
    tag_name: 'Eat',
},{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Rice',
    tag_id: 3,
    tag_name: 'Seeds',
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bean',
    tag_id: 1,
    tag_name: 'Eat',
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bean',
    tag_id: 3,
    tag_name: 'Seeds',
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Milk',
    tag_id: 2,
    tag_name: 'Drink',
},{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Milk',
    tag_id: 4,
    tag_name: 'Cow',
}]
```

Which I parse by hand and aggregate each `product` instance with an array of zero or more `tag` objects that it is associated with.

### Question

When doing the `select` above, the output is 6 rows. However, there are only 3 `products`. Is it possible to use a `limit` clause that would apply to just the `products`?

For example, if `Product.id => 1` had 10 `tags` associated with it, doing a `LIMIT 5` would only select 5 of the tags. What I want to do is select 5 `products` along with all tags associated with it.

The only way I can think of achieving this is to select just the `products`, then do an unbounded `SELECT` with just the product IDs from the previous query.

### Bonus question

Is there a more efficient way to do this `JOIN` such that the output is aggregated as above?

Comment: The only results in SQL are 2-dimensional tables. If you want to reorganize the results into more complex data you have to do it in an external programming language like PHP or Python.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-to-combine-an-array-in-javascript/24302781#24302781 for how to do it in Javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473174/creating-one-array-from-another-array-in-php for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to select 5 products, then join with tags:

```
SELECT p.name as product, t.name AS tag
FROM (
    SELECT id, name
    FROM products
    ORDER by name
    LIMIT 5) AS p
JOIN product_tags AS pt ON pt.product_id = p.id
JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.id
```