# How to return a nested query as a sub-object in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a query that gets some meta data about an object, and then fetches comments that were made on that object. I would like my express framework to send the comments back as a nested object, but instead it's sending multiple "rows" with duplicated data.

Query result/response sent to client:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
[0]     first_name: 'bob',
[0]     last_name: 'masd',
[0]     corkboardID: 1,
[0]     title: 'asd',
[0]     datetime_created: 2018-11-21T17:37:02.000Z,
[0]     image_url: 'http://example.com',
[0]     description: 'asdf',
[0]     tags: 'awesome,cool',
[0]     WriterFname: 'billy',
[0]     WriterLname: 'flimbob',
[0]     text: 'M COMMENT',
[0]     CmtWrittenAt: 2018-11-21T17:37:02.000Z },
[0]   RowDataPacket {
[0]     first_name: 'bob',
[0]     last_name: 'masd',
[0]     corkboardID: 1,
[0]     title: 'asd',
[0]     datetime_created: 2018-11-21T17:37:02.000Z,
[0]     image_url: 'http://example.com',
[0]     description: 'asdf',
[0]     tags: 'awesome,cool',
[0]     WriterFname: 'jim',
[0]     WriterLname: 'lurk',
[0]     text: 'RESPONSE',
[0]     CmtWrittenAt: 2018-11-21T17:37:03.000Z } ]
```

This is the relevant stuff from my query

```
      SELECT
      ...
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Tag.name) AS tags,
Cmt.first_name AS WriterFname,
Cmt.last_name AS WriterLname,
Cmt.text,
Cmt.datetime_created AS CmtWrittenAt
    FROM
      ...
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
          User.first_name,
          User.last_name,
          Comment.text,
          Comment.datetime_created
        FROM
          Comment
          INNER JOIN User ON User.userID = Comment.userID
        WHERE
          Comment.pushpinID = ?
      ) AS Cmt
      ...
    GROUP BY
      ...
      WriterFname,WriterLname,CmtWrittenAt,Cmt.text
```

As you can see I'm already grouping 'tags' and sending that back as an array, and I'd like to group Comment/Cmt as a nested object.

I have gotten close by using `JSON_OBJECT('fname',Cmt.first_name,'lname',Cmt.last_name,'text',Cmt.text,'time',Cmt.datetime_created) AS Comment`, which gives the following:

```
[0] [ RowDataPacket {
[0]     first_name: 'zxc',
[0]     last_name: 'zxc',
[0]     corkboardID: 1,
[0]     title: 'asd',
[0]     datetime_created: 2018-11-21T17:37:02.000Z,
[0]     image_url: 'http://example.com',
[0]     description: 'asdf',
[0]     tags: 'awesome,cool',
[0]     Comment:
[0]      '{"text": "M COMMENT", "time": "2018-11-21 09:37:02.000000", "fname": "asd", "lname": "asd"}' },
[0]   RowDataPacket {
[0]     first_name: 'zxc',
[0]     last_name: 'zxc',
[0]     corkboardID: 1,
[0]     title: 'asd',
[0]     datetime_created: 2018-11-21T17:37:02.000Z,
[0]     image_url: 'http://example.com',
[0]     description: 'asdf',
[0]     tags: 'awesome,cool',
[0]     Comment:
[0]      '{"text": "RESPONSE", "time": "2018-11-21 09:37:03.000000", "fname": "qwe", "lname": "qwe"}' } ]
```

But this still has a lot of duplicated data

Comment: SQL deals with simple tables of data, there's no hierarchical data. If you want to organize the results, you need to do that in JavaScript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-combine-the-array-in-javascript/24302781#24302781 for example.

Comment: @Barmar there's no way to return hierarchical data? I was thinking I could return each column as an array using JSON_ARRAYAGG which seems to work ok, although it has duplicated the rows. At that point may be better to just write a second query I guess

Comment: You don't need a second query. Just go through the array of results and combine the related rows in the JavaScript array of objects.

Comment: @Barmar that's a possibility, im just trying to do it all in SQL

Comment: Can you update the question to show the result you're trying to get? If you use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` you shouldn't get duplicate rows.

Comment: There is no way to return hierarchical data in mysql period. If you return json or xml from a query, that is still just a string value as far as mysql is concerned. You may be able to use json and other string aggregation functions to produce an output that can be interpreted by js as hierarchical dataset, but that is unlikely to be an efficient solution. I would also construct the hierarchical dataset within js based on a simple, flat sql resultset.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Shadow if you want to respond I'll accept that comment as an answer