# NodeJS JSON Structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I currently have a json array structured like this:

```
[{"id": 1, "meeting": "1/3/2015 12:30:00 PM", "name": "John"},
{"id": 1, "meeting": "1/3/2015 13:30:00 PM"}, "name": "John"},
{"id": 2, "meeting": "1/5/2015 7:00:00 AM"}, "name": "Peter"},
{"id": 2, "meeting": "1/5/2015 8:00:00 AM"}, "name": "Peter"}]
```

How can I change the structure of my array to look like this?

```
[ {"id": 1, "name": "John", "meeting": [{"Time": "1/3/2015 12:30:00 PM", "Time": "1/3/2015 13:30:00 PM"}]},
{"id": 2, "name": "Peter", "meeting": [{"Time": "1/5/2015 7:00:00 AM", "Time": "1/5/2015 8:00:00 AM"}]}]
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to group elements by their id. Shouldn't the last element also have id 2, based on this example?

Comment: First off, this isn't JSON.  This is a Javascript array.  JSON is a [text format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: @ArtemKobets Yes. That is what I want to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-to-combine-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
const data = [{"id": 1, "meeting": "1/3/2015 12:30:00 PM", "name": "John"}, {"id": 1, "meeting": "1/3/2015 13:30:00 PM", "name": "John"}, {"id": 2, "meeting": "1/5/2015 7:00:00 AM", "name": "Peter"}, {"id": 2, "meeting": "1/5/2015 8:00:00 AM", "name": "Peter"}];

//I fixed a typo in the above array

const merged = data.reduce((acc, { id, meeting, name }) => {
    if (acc.some(e => e.id == id)) {
        acc.find(e => e.id == id).meeting.push(meeting);
    } else {
        acc.push({ "id": id, "name": name, "meeting": [meeting]});
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: No problem @DanielFer.