# Parse all JSON object with same id value

Tags: javascript, json

I got this JSON response:

```
{"beatmapset_id":"971561","beatmap_id":"2034200","approved":"3","total_length":"196","hit_length":"186","version":"Easy","file_md5":"9c8eb80f6e245b5b0a0a100bbb3e274c","diff_size":"4","diff_overall":"7","diff_approach":"5","diff_drain":"7","mode":"3","submit_date":"2019-05-14 12:01:13","approved_date":"2019-05-22 15:49:35","last_update":"2019-05-22 11:51:06","artist":"antiPLUR","title":"Runengon","creator":"Raveille","creator_id":"1388767","bpm":"174","source":"osu!","tags":"featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"1","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":null,"diff_aim":null,"diff_speed":null,"difficultyrating":"1.2615262269973755"},{"beatmapset_id":"971561","beatmap_id":"2034201","approved":"3","total_length":"196","hit_length":"196","version":"Hard","file_md5":"b5fbe1a1444e35ecb7f8f03e2b61986b","diff_size":"4","diff_overall":"8","diff_approach":"5","diff_drain":"8","mode":"3","submit_date":"2019-05-14 12:01:13","approved_date":"2019-05-22 15:49:35","last_update":"2019-05-22 11:51:06","artist":"antiPLUR","title":"Runengon","creator":"Raveille","creator_id":"1388767","bpm":"174","source":"osu!","tags":"featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"1","rating":"0","playcount":"27","passcount":"9","max_combo":null,"diff_aim":null,"diff_speed":null,"difficultyrating":"3.590883255004883"},{"beatmapset_id":"971561","beatmap_id":"2034202","approved":"3","total_length":"196","hit_length":"196","version":"Normal","file_md5":"f7f23e1073b508593d98cb50097b0d7e","diff_size":"4","diff_overall":"7.5","diff_approach":"5","diff_drain":"7.5","mode":"3","submit_date":"2019-05-14 12:01:13","approved_date":"2019-05-22 15:49:35","last_update":"2019-05-22 11:51:06","artist":"antiPLUR","title":"Runengon","creator":"Raveille","creator_id":"1388767","bpm":"174","source":"osu!","tags":"featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"1","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":null,"diff_aim":null,"diff_speed":null,"difficultyrating":"2.367466926574707"},{"beatmapset_id":"971561","beatmap_id":"2039384","approved":"3","total_length":"196","hit_length":"189","version":"Lenfried's Insane","file_md5":"de4b9a01bf44a847b7cebb96da623ccf","diff_size":"4","diff_overall":"8.5","diff_approach":"5","diff_drain":"8.5","mode":"3","submit_date":"2019-05-14 12:01:13","approved_date":"2019-05-22 15:49:35","last_update":"2019-05-22 11:51:06","artist":"antiPLUR","title":"Runengon","creator":"Raveille","creator_id":"1388767","bpm":"174","source":"osu!","tags":"featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"1","rating":"0","playcount":"9","passcount":"0","max_combo":null,"diff_aim":null,"diff_speed":null,"difficultyrating":"4.318020820617676"},{"beatmapset_id":"747507","beatmap_id":"1575098","approved":"3","total_length":"199","hit_length":"183","version":"Collab Hard","file_md5":"bc4b04103cd263b039fc8349420493a7","diff_size":"3.8","diff_overall":"6","diff_approach":"7.5","diff_drain":"5","mode":"0","submit_date":"2018-03-11 14:14:22","approved_date":"2019-05-22 16:36:04","last_update":"2019-05-21 12:48:00","artist":"senya","title":"Terasareru kurai no Shiawase","creator":"Satellite","creator_id":"1661227","bpm":"160","source":"\u6771\u65b9Project","tags":"\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"11","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":"839","diff_aim":"1.5965542793273926","diff_speed":"1.6582205295562744","difficultyrating":"3.2856078147888184"},{"beatmapset_id":"747507","beatmap_id":"1575099","approved":"3","total_length":"199","hit_length":"182","version":"Koume's Lunatic","file_md5":"7851625279d6e841ef810ced825d8f5a","diff_size":"3.8","diff_overall":"8","diff_approach":"9","diff_drain":"5.5","mode":"0","submit_date":"2018-03-11 14:14:22","approved_date":"2019-05-22 16:36:04","last_update":"2019-05-21 12:48:00","artist":"senya","title":"Terasareru kurai no Shiawase","creator":"Satellite","creator_id":"1661227","bpm":"160","source":"\u6771\u65b9Project","tags":"\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"11","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":"1022","diff_aim":"2.5197982788085938","diff_speed":"2.2990376949310303","difficultyrating":"4.929216384887695"},{"beatmapset_id":"747507","beatmap_id":"1575100","approved":"3","total_length":"199","hit_length":"197","version":"Mo's Lunatic","file_md5":"9572a8b9f12005624ac623f889f5faba","diff_size":"4.2","diff_overall":"7.6","diff_approach":"8.8","diff_drain":"6","mode":"0","submit_date":"2018-03-11 14:14:22","approved_date":"2019-05-22 16:36:04","last_update":"2019-05-21 12:48:00","artist":"senya","title":"Terasareru kurai no Shiawase","creator":"Satellite","creator_id":"1661227","bpm":"160","source":"\u6771\u65b9Project","tags":"\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"11","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":"1108","diff_aim":"2.3829450607299805","diff_speed":"2.201321601867676","difficultyrating":"4.675078392028809"},{"beatmapset_id":"747507","beatmap_id":"1575101","approved":"3","total_length":"199","hit_length":"182","version":"Satellite","file_md5":"db69457a6d3eda63c9de4af73c556bee","diff_size":"4","diff_overall":"8.4","diff_approach":"9.2","diff_drain":"6.2","mode":"0","submit_date":"2018-03-11 14:14:22","approved_date":"2019-05-22 16:36:04","last_update":"2019-05-21 12:48:00","artist":"senya","title":"Terasareru kurai no Shiawase","creator":"Satellite","creator_id":"1661227","bpm":"160","source":"\u6771\u65b9Project","tags":"\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"11","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":"1138","diff_aim":"2.7451868057250977","diff_speed":"2.3703885078430176","difficultyrating":"5.302974224090576"},{"beatmapset_id":"747507","beatmap_id":"1643432","approved":"3","total_length":"199","hit_length":"183","version":"Sellenite's Normal","file_md5":"2f143083aa9bc12f94318d467a2cdd41","diff_size":"3.5","diff_overall":"4","diff_approach":"5.5","diff_drain":"4","mode":"0","submit_date":"2018-03-11 14:14:22","approved_date":"2019-05-22 16:36:04","last_update":"2019-05-21 12:48:00","artist":"senya","title":"Terasareru kurai no Shiawase","creator":"Satellite","creator_id":"1661227","bpm":"160","source":"\u6771\u65b9Project","tags":"\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"11","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":"584","diff_aim":"1.1335170269012451","diff_speed":"1.0233529806137085","difficultyrating":"2.211951971054077"},{"beatmapset_id":"747507","beatmap_id":"1659358","approved":"3","total_length":"199","hit_length":"173","version":"Easy","file_md5":"5ede8b76217cbf0e22980e990905181d","diff_size":"3","diff_overall":"2","diff_approach":"3","diff_drain":"2","mode":"0","submit_date":"2018-03-11 14:14:22","approved_date":"2019-05-22 16:36:04","last_update":"2019-05-21 12:48:00","artist":"senya","title":"Terasareru kurai no Shiawase","creator":"Satellite","creator_id":"1661227","bpm":"160","source":"\u6771\u65b9Project","tags":"\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei","genre_id":"1","language_id":"1","favourite_count":"11","rating":"0","playcount":"0","passcount":"0","max_combo":"483","diff_aim":"1.0374764204025269","diff_speed":"0.9278122186660767","difficultyrating":"2.020120620727539"}]
```

I want to parse all "difficultyrating" from all objects with same beatmapset_id value and put it into array. How can I do that? I did that to parse only last element from JSON:

```
var latestBeatmap = JSON.stringify(resp[resp.length - 1]);
var parsed = JSON.parse(latestBeatmap);
```

Comment: There's no need to call `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Just use `var parsed = resp[resp.length-1];`

Comment: What do you mean by "same beatmapset_id"? Same as what?

Comment: You left off the `[` at the start of your JSON response.  Also formatting that for us would be super nice.

Comment: I got this error with your solution, mine is working btw SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Couple of objects have same beatmapset_id "971561". I want to parse all "difficultyrating" elements from all objects with same id.

Comment: You mean you want to group the result by `beatmapset_id`?

Comment: I want to parse all "difficultyrating" elements from all objects with same id.

Comment: I don't think you understand what "parse" means. It's already parsed when you turn it into an object. You can use `resp[i].difficultyrating` to access any particular rating.

Comment: Show the result you're trying to get, so we can understand you better.

Comment: Yes but I dont know how many objects I will get. It would be 5 or 2. Second..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-combine-the-array-in-javascript/24302781#24302781 for an example of grouping an array of objects by a property.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mGFp8vj just I want to get all from response which I will get. Objects with same "beatmapset_id" appear in the same time. Once there are 5, twice 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i see in your code, it looks like the answer is already parsed in `resp`. There is no point in stringify that and parsing again, you can just filter the values that you need out of that array.

If what I understood is correct, you want to get all `difficultyrating` of a `beatmapset_id`

You can do it by doing a filter and a map.

e.g.

```
resp.filter(beatmap => beatmap.beatmapset_id === "971561").map(beatmap => beatmap.difficultyrating)
```

will yield:

```
["1.2615262269973755", "3.590883255004883", "2.367466926574707", "4.318020820617676"]
```

If you want to use the last beatmap, you can replace the number with `resp[resp.length - 1].beatmapset_id`

```
resp.filter(beatmap => beatmap.beatmapset_id === resp[resp.length - 1].beatmapset_id).map(beatmap => beatmap.difficultyrating)
```

If you want to group them, you can use reduce like this:

```
bySetId = resp.reduce((bySetId, current) => {
  if (!bySetId[current.beatmapset_id]) {
    bySetId[current.beatmapset_id] = []
  }
  bySetId[current.beatmapset_id].push(current.difficultyrating)
  return bySetId;
}, {});
```

bySetId will have the value:

```
{
  747507: 
    [ "3.2856078147888184", "4.929216384887695", "4.675078392028809", 
      "5.302974224090576", "2.211951971054077", "2.020120620727539"]
  971561: 
    [ "1.2615262269973755", "3.590883255004883", "2.367466926574707", 
      "4.318020820617676"]
}
```

Then you can use that to merge on your previous values If needed.

Comment: More like this but I dont know beatmapset_id before. My Discord Bot is parsing JSON response every second and waiting for elements.

Comment: You want then to group by beatmapset_id?

Comment: If new objects appear in JSON with same beatmapset_id, it will save all "difficultyrating" elements to array from these objects.

Comment: How can I get only latest elements? If new objects with same "beatmapset_id" appear, it will only get them without any others?

Comment: Ah, you want to fix the "beatmapset_id" to the last one of the array? Is that correct? You pick the first code and replace "971561" with `resp[resp.length - 1].beatmapset_id`

Comment: If not, I think you need more details in your question. For example, given that JSON, write your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = [{
 "beatmapset_id": "971561",
 "beatmap_id": "2034200",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "196",
 "hit_length": "186",
 "version": "Easy",
 "file_md5": "9c8eb80f6e245b5b0a0a100bbb3e274c",
 "diff_size": "4",
 "diff_overall": "7",
 "diff_approach": "5",
 "diff_drain": "7",
 "mode": "3",
 "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
 "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
 "artist": "antiPLUR",
 "title": "Runengon",
 "creator": "Raveille",
 "creator_id": "1388767",
 "bpm": "174",
 "source": "osu!",
 "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "1",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": null,
 "diff_aim": null,
 "diff_speed": null,
 "difficultyrating": "1.2615262269973755"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "971561",
 "beatmap_id": "2034201",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "196",
 "hit_length": "196",
 "version": "Hard",
 "file_md5": "b5fbe1a1444e35ecb7f8f03e2b61986b",
 "diff_size": "4",
 "diff_overall": "8",
 "diff_approach": "5",
 "diff_drain": "8",
 "mode": "3",
 "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
 "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
 "artist": "antiPLUR",
 "title": "Runengon",
 "creator": "Raveille",
 "creator_id": "1388767",
 "bpm": "174",
 "source": "osu!",
 "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "1",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "27",
 "passcount": "9",
 "max_combo": null,
 "diff_aim": null,
 "diff_speed": null,
 "difficultyrating": "3.590883255004883"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "971561",
 "beatmap_id": "2034202",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "196",
 "hit_length": "196",
 "version": "Normal",
 "file_md5": "f7f23e1073b508593d98cb50097b0d7e",
 "diff_size": "4",
 "diff_overall": "7.5",
 "diff_approach": "5",
 "diff_drain": "7.5",
 "mode": "3",
 "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
 "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
 "artist": "antiPLUR",
 "title": "Runengon",
 "creator": "Raveille",
 "creator_id": "1388767",
 "bpm": "174",
 "source": "osu!",
 "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "1",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": null,
 "diff_aim": null,
 "diff_speed": null,
 "difficultyrating": "2.367466926574707"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "971561",
 "beatmap_id": "2039384",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "196",
 "hit_length": "189",
 "version": "Lenfried's Insane",
 "file_md5": "de4b9a01bf44a847b7cebb96da623ccf",
 "diff_size": "4",
 "diff_overall": "8.5",
 "diff_approach": "5",
 "diff_drain": "8.5",
 "mode": "3",
 "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
 "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
 "artist": "antiPLUR",
 "title": "Runengon",
 "creator": "Raveille",
 "creator_id": "1388767",
 "bpm": "174",
 "source": "osu!",
 "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "1",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "9",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": null,
 "diff_aim": null,
 "diff_speed": null,
 "difficultyrating": "4.318020820617676"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "747507",
 "beatmap_id": "1575098",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "199",
 "hit_length": "183",
 "version": "Collab Hard",
 "file_md5": "bc4b04103cd263b039fc8349420493a7",
 "diff_size": "3.8",
 "diff_overall": "6",
 "diff_approach": "7.5",
 "diff_drain": "5",
 "mode": "0",
 "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
 "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
 "artist": "senya",
 "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
 "creator": "Satellite",
 "creator_id": "1661227",
 "bpm": "160",
 "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
 "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "11",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": "839",
 "diff_aim": "1.5965542793273926",
 "diff_speed": "1.6582205295562744",
 "difficultyrating": "3.2856078147888184"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "747507",
 "beatmap_id": "1575099",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "199",
 "hit_length": "182",
 "version": "Koume's Lunatic",
 "file_md5": "7851625279d6e841ef810ced825d8f5a",
 "diff_size": "3.8",
 "diff_overall": "8",
 "diff_approach": "9",
 "diff_drain": "5.5",
 "mode": "0",
 "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
 "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
 "artist": "senya",
 "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
 "creator": "Satellite",
 "creator_id": "1661227",
 "bpm": "160",
 "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
 "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "11",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": "1022",
 "diff_aim": "2.5197982788085938",
 "diff_speed": "2.2990376949310303",
 "difficultyrating": "4.929216384887695"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "747507",
 "beatmap_id": "1575100",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "199",
 "hit_length": "197",
 "version": "Mo's Lunatic",
 "file_md5": "9572a8b9f12005624ac623f889f5faba",
 "diff_size": "4.2",
 "diff_overall": "7.6",
 "diff_approach": "8.8",
 "diff_drain": "6",
 "mode": "0",
 "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
 "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
 "artist": "senya",
 "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
 "creator": "Satellite",
 "creator_id": "1661227",
 "bpm": "160",
 "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
 "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "11",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": "1108",
 "diff_aim": "2.3829450607299805",
 "diff_speed": "2.201321601867676",
 "difficultyrating": "4.675078392028809"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "747507",
 "beatmap_id": "1575101",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "199",
 "hit_length": "182",
 "version": "Satellite",
 "file_md5": "db69457a6d3eda63c9de4af73c556bee",
 "diff_size": "4",
 "diff_overall": "8.4",
 "diff_approach": "9.2",
 "diff_drain": "6.2",
 "mode": "0",
 "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
 "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
 "artist": "senya",
 "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
 "creator": "Satellite",
 "creator_id": "1661227",
 "bpm": "160",
 "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
 "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "11",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": "1138",
 "diff_aim": "2.7451868057250977",
 "diff_speed": "2.3703885078430176",
 "difficultyrating": "5.302974224090576"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "747507",
 "beatmap_id": "1643432",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "199",
 "hit_length": "183",
 "version": "Sellenite's Normal",
 "file_md5": "2f143083aa9bc12f94318d467a2cdd41",
 "diff_size": "3.5",
 "diff_overall": "4",
 "diff_approach": "5.5",
 "diff_drain": "4",
 "mode": "0",
 "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
 "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
 "artist": "senya",
 "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
 "creator": "Satellite",
 "creator_id": "1661227",
 "bpm": "160",
 "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
 "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "11",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": "584",
 "diff_aim": "1.1335170269012451",
 "diff_speed": "1.0233529806137085",
 "difficultyrating": "2.211951971054077"
}, {
 "beatmapset_id": "747507",
 "beatmap_id": "1659358",
 "approved": "3",
 "total_length": "199",
 "hit_length": "173",
 "version": "Easy",
 "file_md5": "5ede8b76217cbf0e22980e990905181d",
 "diff_size": "3",
 "diff_overall": "2",
 "diff_approach": "3",
 "diff_drain": "2",
 "mode": "0",
 "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
 "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
 "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
 "artist": "senya",
 "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
 "creator": "Satellite",
 "creator_id": "1661227",
 "bpm": "160",
 "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
 "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
 "genre_id": "1",
 "language_id": "1",
 "favourite_count": "11",
 "rating": "0",
 "playcount": "0",
 "passcount": "0",
 "max_combo": "483",
 "diff_aim": "1.0374764204025269",
 "diff_speed": "0.9278122186660767",
 "difficultyrating": "2.020120620727539"
}];


var extract_beatmapset_id = input.map((item) => {
  return {
  beatmapset_id:item.beatmapset_id,
  difficultyrating:item.difficultyrating
  }
});
var result = {};
extract_beatmapset_id.forEach((item)=>{
  if(!result[item.beatmapset_id]){
    result[item.beatmapset_id] = [];
  }
   result[item.beatmapset_id].push(item.difficultyrating);
});

console.log(result)
```

You can execute the code without extract too.. But its preferable to extract items on focus so we dont disturb other items by mistake (only suggestion).

Comment: Check the console.log for result

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Set` and `map` to do this:

```
const beatMapToDifficulty = [...new Set(beatmapResp.map(b =>b.beatmapset_id))]
            .map(bm => ({
               beatmapset_id: bm, 
               difficultyratings: beatmapResp.filter(br => br.beatmapset_id === bm)
                                             .map(b => b.difficultyrating)
               }));

console.log(beatMapToDifficulty);
```

Below is working snippet of this code.

```js
const beatmapResp = [{
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2034200",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "186",
  "version": "Easy",
  "file_md5": "9c8eb80f6e245b5b0a0a100bbb3e274c",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "7",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "7",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "1.2615262269973755"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2034201",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "196",
  "version": "Hard",
  "file_md5": "b5fbe1a1444e35ecb7f8f03e2b61986b",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "8",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "8",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "27",
  "passcount": "9",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "3.590883255004883"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2034202",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "196",
  "version": "Normal",
  "file_md5": "f7f23e1073b508593d98cb50097b0d7e",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "7.5",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "7.5",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "2.367466926574707"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2039384",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "189",
  "version": "Lenfried's Insane",
  "file_md5": "de4b9a01bf44a847b7cebb96da623ccf",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "8.5",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "8.5",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "9",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "4.318020820617676"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575098",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "183",
  "version": "Collab Hard",
  "file_md5": "bc4b04103cd263b039fc8349420493a7",
  "diff_size": "3.8",
  "diff_overall": "6",
  "diff_approach": "7.5",
  "diff_drain": "5",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "839",
  "diff_aim": "1.5965542793273926",
  "diff_speed": "1.6582205295562744",
  "difficultyrating": "3.2856078147888184"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575099",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "182",
  "version": "Koume's Lunatic",
  "file_md5": "7851625279d6e841ef810ced825d8f5a",
  "diff_size": "3.8",
  "diff_overall": "8",
  "diff_approach": "9",
  "diff_drain": "5.5",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "1022",
  "diff_aim": "2.5197982788085938",
  "diff_speed": "2.2990376949310303",
  "difficultyrating": "4.929216384887695"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575100",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "197",
  "version": "Mo's Lunatic",
  "file_md5": "9572a8b9f12005624ac623f889f5faba",
  "diff_size": "4.2",
  "diff_overall": "7.6",
  "diff_approach": "8.8",
  "diff_drain": "6",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "1108",
  "diff_aim": "2.3829450607299805",
  "diff_speed": "2.201321601867676",
  "difficultyrating": "4.675078392028809"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575101",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "182",
  "version": "Satellite",
  "file_md5": "db69457a6d3eda63c9de4af73c556bee",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "8.4",
  "diff_approach": "9.2",
  "diff_drain": "6.2",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "1138",
  "diff_aim": "2.7451868057250977",
  "diff_speed": "2.3703885078430176",
  "difficultyrating": "5.302974224090576"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1643432",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "183",
  "version": "Sellenite's Normal",
  "file_md5": "2f143083aa9bc12f94318d467a2cdd41",
  "diff_size": "3.5",
  "diff_overall": "4",
  "diff_approach": "5.5",
  "diff_drain": "4",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "584",
  "diff_aim": "1.1335170269012451",
  "diff_speed": "1.0233529806137085",
  "difficultyrating": "2.211951971054077"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1659358",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "173",
  "version": "Easy",
  "file_md5": "5ede8b76217cbf0e22980e990905181d",
  "diff_size": "3",
  "diff_overall": "2",
  "diff_approach": "3",
  "diff_drain": "2",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "483",
  "diff_aim": "1.0374764204025269",
  "diff_speed": "0.9278122186660767",
  "difficultyrating": "2.020120620727539"
}];

const beatMapToDifficulty = [...new Set(beatmapResp.map(b =>b.beatmapset_id))]
                .map(bm => ({
                   beatmapset_id: bm, 
                   difficultyratings: beatmapResp.filter(br => br.beatmapset_id === bm)
                                                 .map(b => b.difficultyrating)
                   }));
                            
console.log(beatMapToDifficulty);
```

To get just the `last` difficulty and not all:

We use `reverse`

```
    const beatMapToDifficulty = [...new Set(beatmapResp.map(b =>b.beatmapset_id))]
            .map(bm => ({
               beatmapset_id: bm, 
               difficultyratings: beatmapResp.reverse().find(br => 
                                  br.beatmapset_id === bm).difficultyrating

               }));
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
const beatmapResp = [{
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2034200",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "186",
  "version": "Easy",
  "file_md5": "9c8eb80f6e245b5b0a0a100bbb3e274c",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "7",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "7",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "1.2615262269973755"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2034201",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "196",
  "version": "Hard",
  "file_md5": "b5fbe1a1444e35ecb7f8f03e2b61986b",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "8",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "8",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "27",
  "passcount": "9",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "3.590883255004883"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2034202",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "196",
  "version": "Normal",
  "file_md5": "f7f23e1073b508593d98cb50097b0d7e",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "7.5",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "7.5",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "2.367466926574707"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "971561",
  "beatmap_id": "2039384",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "196",
  "hit_length": "189",
  "version": "Lenfried's Insane",
  "file_md5": "de4b9a01bf44a847b7cebb96da623ccf",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "8.5",
  "diff_approach": "5",
  "diff_drain": "8.5",
  "mode": "3",
  "submit_date": "2019-05-14 12:01:13",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 15:49:35",
  "last_update": "2019-05-22 11:51:06",
  "artist": "antiPLUR",
  "title": "Runengon",
  "creator": "Raveille",
  "creator_id": "1388767",
  "bpm": "174",
  "source": "osu!",
  "tags": "featured artist lenfried- famoss mappers' guild fa chiptune 8bit aaron dictor electronic",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "1",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "9",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": null,
  "diff_aim": null,
  "diff_speed": null,
  "difficultyrating": "4.318020820617676"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575098",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "183",
  "version": "Collab Hard",
  "file_md5": "bc4b04103cd263b039fc8349420493a7",
  "diff_size": "3.8",
  "diff_overall": "6",
  "diff_approach": "7.5",
  "diff_drain": "5",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "839",
  "diff_aim": "1.5965542793273926",
  "diff_speed": "1.6582205295562744",
  "difficultyrating": "3.2856078147888184"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575099",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "182",
  "version": "Koume's Lunatic",
  "file_md5": "7851625279d6e841ef810ced825d8f5a",
  "diff_size": "3.8",
  "diff_overall": "8",
  "diff_approach": "9",
  "diff_drain": "5.5",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "1022",
  "diff_aim": "2.5197982788085938",
  "diff_speed": "2.2990376949310303",
  "difficultyrating": "4.929216384887695"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575100",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "197",
  "version": "Mo's Lunatic",
  "file_md5": "9572a8b9f12005624ac623f889f5faba",
  "diff_size": "4.2",
  "diff_overall": "7.6",
  "diff_approach": "8.8",
  "diff_drain": "6",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "1108",
  "diff_aim": "2.3829450607299805",
  "diff_speed": "2.201321601867676",
  "difficultyrating": "4.675078392028809"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1575101",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "182",
  "version": "Satellite",
  "file_md5": "db69457a6d3eda63c9de4af73c556bee",
  "diff_size": "4",
  "diff_overall": "8.4",
  "diff_approach": "9.2",
  "diff_drain": "6.2",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "1138",
  "diff_aim": "2.7451868057250977",
  "diff_speed": "2.3703885078430176",
  "difficultyrating": "5.302974224090576"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1643432",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "183",
  "version": "Sellenite's Normal",
  "file_md5": "2f143083aa9bc12f94318d467a2cdd41",
  "diff_size": "3.5",
  "diff_overall": "4",
  "diff_approach": "5.5",
  "diff_drain": "4",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "584",
  "diff_aim": "1.1335170269012451",
  "diff_speed": "1.0233529806137085",
  "difficultyrating": "2.211951971054077"
}, {
  "beatmapset_id": "747507",
  "beatmap_id": "1659358",
  "approved": "3",
  "total_length": "199",
  "hit_length": "173",
  "version": "Easy",
  "file_md5": "5ede8b76217cbf0e22980e990905181d",
  "diff_size": "3",
  "diff_overall": "2",
  "diff_approach": "3",
  "diff_drain": "2",
  "mode": "0",
  "submit_date": "2018-03-11 14:14:22",
  "approved_date": "2019-05-22 16:36:04",
  "last_update": "2019-05-21 12:48:00",
  "artist": "senya",
  "title": "Terasareru kurai no Shiawase",
  "creator": "Satellite",
  "creator_id": "1661227",
  "bpm": "160",
  "source": "\u6771\u65b9Project",
  "tags": "\u5e7d\u9589\u30b5\u30c6\u30e9\u30a4\u30c8 touhou sellenite dailycare -mo- shirasaka_koume voyage 1969 \u6771\u65b9\u6c38\u591c\u6284 imperishable night stage 6 theme \u304b\u307e\u305b\u864e kamasetora \u795e\u5948\u68ee\u30e6\u30a6 hizumi \u96f6\u308c\u305a\u306e\u9858\u3044\u30b4\u30c8 koborezu no negai goto dagger-gazel yuuhei",
  "genre_id": "1",
  "language_id": "1",
  "favourite_count": "11",
  "rating": "0",
  "playcount": "0",
  "passcount": "0",
  "max_combo": "483",
  "diff_aim": "1.0374764204025269",
  "diff_speed": "0.9278122186660767",
  "difficultyrating": "2.020120620727539"
}];

const beatMapToDifficulty = [...new Set(beatmapResp.map(b =>b.beatmapset_id))]
                .map(bm => ({
                   beatmapset_id: bm, 
                   difficultyratings: beatmapResp.reverse()
                                                  .find(br => br.beatmapset_id === bm)
                                                  .difficultyrating
                   }));
                            
console.log(beatMapToDifficulty);
```

Comment: Yes, it works but how can I get only latest elements? If new objects with same "beatmapset_id" appear, it will only get them without any others?

Comment: Ah, so you want the `last` difficulty for a given `beatmapset_id` ?

Comment: @kjoszi added option showing last result, is that what you wanted?