# How to covert MySQL rows into JSON response using node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

I'm trying to create a mark sheet application for Schools.

I would like to display the marks entered by the teachers in the Angular web application.

I have a MySQL table like this,

```
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------+
| Roll_no |     Subject |    Category  | Marks |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------+
|   1     |    English  |  HomeWork 1  |  10   |
|   1     |    English  |  HomeWork 2  |  10   |
|   1     |    Science  |  HomeWork 1  |  10   |
|   1     |    Science  |  HomeWork 2  |  10   |
|   2     |    English  |  HomeWork 1  |  10   |
|   2     |    English  |  HomeWork 2  |  10   |
|   2     |    Science  |  HomeWork 1  |  10   |
|   2     |    Science  |  HomeWork 2  |  10   |
+---------+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

How to convert this into a JSON response like this,

```
[
 {
   "Roll_no" : 1,
   "Marks" : [
     {
       "English" : [ "HomeWork 1" : "10" , "HomeWork 2" : "10" ] ,
       "Science" : [ "HomeWork 1" : "10" , "HomeWork 2" : "10" ]
     }
 },
 {
   "Roll_no" : 2,
   "Marks" : [
     {
       "English" : [ "HomeWork 1" : "10" , "HomeWork 2" : "10" ] ,
       "Science" : [ "HomeWork 1" : "10" , "HomeWork 2" : "10" ]
     }
 }
]
```

using SQL queries and node.js?

I'm using,
node.js V10.0
Angular V7.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be easier if you made the top-level an object using the roll number as the key. You can easily convert that object to an array at the end of the loop.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302630/how-combine-the-array-in-javascript/24302781#24302781 for the general structure of looping over the array of database results.